# How to use NuGet 4.x with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I am stuck with VS 2015 because we still have Silverlight bits (porting to HTML is underway). Hence I cannot use VS 2017 (I can, but not for all the code, which is a pain).

VS 2015 does not allow me to install NuGet packages that use features only available in NuGet 4.x, because the NuGet package manager for VS 2015 is equivalent to NuGet 3.x

Is it possible to make VS 2015 work with NuGet 4.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make VS 2015 work with NuGet 4.x ?

I am afraid you can Not do that. Because NuGet Package Manager extension 4.x is not a separate extension, it is built-in the Visual Studio 2017, we could not get it from [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

Besides, the [Announcing NuGet 4.0 RTM](https://blog.nuget.org/20170308/Announcing-NuGet-4.0-RTM.html) also pointed this:

> T**he NuGet 4.0 Package Manager Extension is currently not available for
>   Visual Studio 2015** (Visual Studio 2015 comes with NuGet 3.4.4, and
>   NuGet 3.5.0 is available as an explicit download for Visual Studio
>   2015 as well). **NuGet 4.0 builds upon several new features and bug
>   fixes available only in Visual Studio 2017**, and hence the newer NuGet
>   experiences will not be available in Visual Studio 2015.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. NuGet 4.x is part of Visual Studio 2017 and for Visual Studio 2015, the last version is [3.6.0](https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/v3.6.0/NuGet.Tools.vsix).